# Mark Email "Unread" from Email full view

Tags: iphone, ios, mail.app, email

I have been switched to iPhone (iPhone 6s with iOS 9.2) from Android a few days ago. Previously in my Android "Email" software, I could mark that email Read/Unread from the full view. But in my iPhone "Mail" software, if I am in a full view of email I cannot find any option to mark it as "Unread". I need to go back to the list to do that. Can anyone suggest, am I missing something here?

(Pls be clear that I know how to do it from the "Inbox" list, so please don't put any answer / link suggesting that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on the flag (bottom left) and choose Mark as unread.

Comment: Wow! I thought it is only for flagging. Poor placement. Anyways, thanks for your help.